# How to include one .js file into another in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For simplicity, I've created 3 files. I want to include them accordingly. But I don't know how to do it. For example, I want **server.js** to include **routes.js**, and **routes.js** would need **handlers.js** So that I can execute server.js successfully. I tried to include them using `require` but it showed errors like `server is not defined`. Is there any way to do it?

Here are my files:

**server.js**

```
var restify = require('restify');
var server = restify.createServer();
require('./routes.js');
server.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('%s is listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

**routes.js**

```
server.get('/get', getHandler);
server.put('/update', putHandler);
server.post('/post', postHandler);
server.delete('/delete', delHandler);
```

**handlers.js**

```
function getHandler(req, res, next){
    connectionPool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            res.send({
                Error: err,
                Message: "Can't connect Database."
            });
        }else{
            //queries
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM book", function(err, rows, fields){
                res.send(rows);
            })
        }
    })
}
```

NOTE: Some users have marked it duplicate but that answer doesn't solve my problem. That answer doesn't explain how to include A into B and B into A. I need routes.js to include server.js and server.js to include routes.js. How can I do this? The anser only explain how to include a function.

Comment: It's not duplicate. That answer just show how to include a function. That doesn't explain how to include A into B and B into A.

Comment: Some users have marked it duplicate but that answer doesn't solve my problem. That answer doesn't explain how to include A into B and B into A. I need routes.js to include server.js and server.js to include routes.js. How can I do this? The anser only explain how to include a function.

Comment: At first you should require server.js and handlers.js modules in routes.js, node.js modules arent working like php code, you have to require every module in every place you use it

Comment: @VikasKumar you have to use `require()`, there is no "include" in Node.

Comment: Do not close this, his question is valid and the other answer does not solve it's problem. He needs it's inner module to have access to the parent variables. It's need to explained how to do this.

Comment: @styopdev require doesn't work.

Comment: @VikasKumar send your server as a parameter to an init function  inside routes.js. Would write your some code, but they closed it

Comment: @VikasKumar there is no require in routes.js you have provided

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? What is init function?

Comment: @O_Z the question for which this one is marked as a duplicate does show how to export a function. It should follow that you would be able to pass variables, like `server`, to such a function.

Comment: If there's no require in routes.js that doesn't mean I didn't try it. @styopdev

Comment: @VikasKumar if you don't know how modules, or functions, work in Node, you should probably start with a tutorial on the matter.

Comment: @O_Z it worked for those 2 files. I read your edit. Now I'm getting error 'getHandler' is not defined. It looks more complicated now. How can I do it?

Comment: @robertklep now I'm getting error 'getHandler' is not defined. Do you think that question can solve it?

Comment: @VikasKumar yes; the `getHandler` function needs to be exported (and subsequently `require`'d in `routes.js`), but the principle is very much the same.

Comment: No I only solved your server Error. Check solution again I added aline about it.This is really standart.

Comment: @robertklep @O_Z I moved my all 4 handlers (not listed in this question's details) inside a new function `some` with 4 parameters named same as handler functions. Then I wrote `exports.some=some` and finally required in routes.js by writing: `require('./handlers.js').some(4 parameters)` but it doesn't work. It still shows handler not defined.

Comment: @VikasKumar [here's an example](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/7572ccf3990f580333005c6db168c145)

Comment: Now it is showing that getHandler is an unexpected identifier (in handlers.js)

Comment: I've tried these things but still I'm facing problem. I've shared it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422845/why-is-there-connectionpool-not-defined-error Could you please check?

Comment: Please somebody check the above link.